# how to resurrect a jdbc connection after failure?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am developing an program that uses transactions, for data integrity.

I have read about jdbc savepoints where one can rollback to a point where there was no error in the transaction.

But there is one situation, say the network fails, that makes the connection handling the transaction to be invalid.

Now i have managed to detect in my program whenever a network problem occurs, make appear a dialog that will block the ui for 2 minutes while trying to establish a connection to the db.

my question is, is there a way to save a transaction, not a savepoint, or re establish the connection where a network failure occured in during the transaction, so that if connection is re established, we can continue with the prevous queries?

why i want this is because my program will perform transactions over multiple modal dialogs before commit, say dialog A queries were successfull, when we go to dialog B before committing, if a network error occurs here we should be able to continue where we left off in dialog A.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should store state in memory and do all the updates after the last modal dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspending a database transaction during "user think-time" is bad news.  A more appropriate strategy is to use "versioning".

This is done by adding a column to your record that increments with every update.  When a user reviews the record to think about changes, the version is loaded.  When the changes are applied, the version is compared to ensure it has not changed.  If it has changed, you have a "soft deadlock", which can be addressed in a few ways:

1. Warn the user that another change has been made, and ask to confirm an overwrite
2. Present the user with a list of updates that occurred during their think-time, and if they want to overwrite them.  This can be tricky because you should refresh the version number for the confirmation, recheck it if they choose to overwrite, and give them yet another warning/confirmation if something changed while they were deciding to overwrite.  Your process should be designed to do this forever if necessary.
3. Prevent the update outright

Answer (score 1):

If your main concern is data integrity and ODBC backend database is ACID-compliant, then you do not need to worry. Simply re-do the transaction after re-establishing the connection, and that will work just fine.